# Does the fact that $\tan^2(x)={\sin^2x\over \cos^2x}$ on $(-{\pi\over 2},{\pi\over 2})$ means $\{\tan^2(x),\cos^2x,\sin^2x\}$ are linearly dependent?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does the fact that $\tan^2(x)={\sin^2x\over \cos^2x}$ on $(-{\pi\over 2},{\pi\over 2})$ mean $\{\tan,\cos,\sin\}$ is linearly dependent?

I am not sure what to say. It does mean that. Doesn't it? What am I missing here to be asked such a seemingly trivial question?

Comment: I did. I edited.

Comment: It might help you stop using bad notation. What you really want to ask is whether the set $\{\tan, \sin, \cos\}$ is linearly dependent (where the vector space is, for instance, the set of continuous functions defined on $\left]-\frac\pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right[$). How do you usually check if vectors are linearly dependent? (Here the vectors are the functions $\tan, \sin$ and $\cos$).

Comment: No, it doesn't "mean" that. It just means what is says: one function is the quotient of the other 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this does not mean your set is L.D, I think what this exercise is about is the following:

Consider a linear combination giving $0$:

$$A\tan^2x+B\cos^2x+C\sin^2x=0\tag 1$$

One might be tempted to say "Let $A=1,B=0,C=-\frac {1}{\cos^2x}$ and we have our nontrivial combination of $A,B,C$ giving us the $0$ function!" but the thing is that $A,B,C$ should be *numbers*, not functions (this is, assuming that the vector space you're talking is $(\Bbb R^{(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)},\Bbb R,\cdot,+)$).

**Remark**

To say that a set of $n$ functions is linearly independent means that if we take a linear combination giving the $0$ **function**:

$$a_1f_1(t)+a_2f_2(t)+...+a_nf_n(t)=0$$

It must be that $a_1=...=a_n=0$ for all $t$.

Going back to our equation (1): Let's evaluate it at $x=0$, we then have

$$A\tan^2(0)+B\cos^2(0)+C\sin^2(0)=B\cos^2(0)=B=0$$

Thus $B=0$, now, if $x\neq 0$ we have that

$$A\tan^2x+C\sin^2x=0\iff A\sec^2x+C=0\iff A\sec^2x=-C$$

Now, we now that $sec^2x$ is not constant, so the only way it can equal a constant for all $x$ is that $A=0$. Looking back at (1), we deduce that $C$ must be $0$ aswell. So your set is $\text{L.I}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose $a\tan^2 x + b\cos^2 x + c\sin^2 x \equiv 0$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ Now one of those functions is unbounded on this interval, so ...

Answer (score 3):

The [Wronksian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of these functions is given by:

$$W(x) = \det \left( \begin{matrix} \sin x & \cos x & \tan x \\ \cos x & -\sin x & 1 + \tan^2 x \\ -\sin x & -\cos x & \tan x(1 + \tan^2 x) \end{matrix} \right)$$

[It simplifies to](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=wronskian+%5B%7Bsinx%2Ccosx%2Ctanx%7D%2C+x%5D):

$$W(x) = -\tan x(1 + 2\sec^2 x)$$

This is not identically zero on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$